# Android kills threads I still need

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a xamarin-android application, working together with an own-written library. In this library the most important thing is a streamreader, always reading the stream. That is why I am starting the reader with `Task.Factory.StartNew(Read(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)`.

Everything works perfectly fine, until it comes to using the library on android. While debugging I saw how a newly created thread for my reading task, immediately gets destroyed in the next line. Can I somehow prevent android from doing that? Do I need to start the routine in a different way? Does it have anything to do with starting the routine in a Button-Click-Event?

Currently, this is the way I am starting the routine. In `client.Connect()` there is the `Task.Factory` starting the reading-task.

```
private void ConnButt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        client=new XMPPClient("172.16.55.96", 5222, "chris", "Define");
        client.OnConnection+=Client_OnConnection;
        client.OnPublishEvent+=Client_OnPublishEvent;
        client.Connect();
}
```

EDIT: I just found out(i guess) why the thread terminates. As soon as my reader-method is called, an auto-property-getter is called. I do not know why it gets called there is no conditioning or anything else. Maybe that could be related.

Comment: Do you get any output messages from the system as to why the thread was killed? I don't know how xamarin translates .net Task stuff to native Android, but I'd expect the Android to handle Thread-related stuff somewhat differently than other systems.

Comment: I found this: https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-background-tasks/ where it says (as I expected) that the way to go on Android is to write a Service for long-running or periodic tasks.

Comment: It just says "The thread 0xX has exited with code 0 (0x0)." as if everything is in order. I will look into your link and try using it as service. I hope that works. Thanks

Comment: @Fildor I tried different approaches with services now. It is still killing my ReadingTask. I'm pretty much cluesless on what and how to try it now.

Comment: Have you tried to make the Connect event asynchronous?
so you can just say private async void ConnButt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        client=new XMPPClient("172.16.55.96", 5222, "chris", "Define");
        client.OnConnection+=Client_OnConnection;
        client.OnPublishEvent+=Client_OnPublishEvent;
        await client.Connect();
}